# Python bigquery lib error 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'decimal256'

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery, pyarrow

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'decimal256'
Appears to be an error of bigquery python package, how should procceed?

The entire stack is:

```
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 70, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery import _pandas_helpers
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 151, in <module>
    pyarrow.decimal256(76, scale=38).id: "BIGNUMERIC",
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'decimal256'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this problem in last week. I solved this today.
The problem is not in google API. The problem is in pyarrow.
I just change the version of pyarrow package for 5.0.0 version (pyarrow==5.0.0) and the problem was solved.